# Finding the filename with the latest modification date that fits a particular pattern

Tags: regex, ms-access, vba, last-modified

I have files at a particular path on my computer that look like "Report Name May 13.xls" and I'd like to be able to reference filenames dynamically. For example, say I wanted to return the latest file that fit the pattern "Report Name <>.xls" where <> is any particular text string. By "latest" I imply the most recent modified date.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the date piece from each file name easily enough, as in this Immediate window session.

```vb
strFile = "Report Name May 13.xls"
? Mid(strFile, 13)
May 13.xls
? Split(Mid(strFile, 13), ".")(0)
May 13
```

Assuming those dates are all from the current year, you can construct a full date string.

```vb
? Split(Mid(strFile, 13), ".")(0) & " " & Year(Date())
May 13 2013
```

Finally you can use `CDate` to convert that string to an actual Date/Time value.

```vb
? CDate(Split(Mid(strFile, 13), ".")(0) & " " & Year(Date()))
5/13/2013
```

So you could have a variable to store the maximum date, walk your list of file names, determine the date associated with each, and store the max date value as needed.

That should not be too difficult.  A greater concern for me is the file names do not include the year.  So that leaves me wondering what will happen on Jan 1 2014.  Will you discard all the *.xls* files and start over?

Comment: This is technically not dynamic enough for my purposes. I am saying that the filename should have (STATIC PORTION)(DYNAMIC PORTION).xls, and I want the latest-modified filename that fits this pattern given the STATIC PORTION is known.

Comment: Are you saying `(STATIC PORTION)` can be something other than `"Report Name "`?

Comment: Yes -- for example say I call the function getLatest(staticString as String, path as String) -- it would return the file located at the path with the latest modified date that fits (static)(dynamic).xls

Comment: In that case, where I have `Mid(strFile, 13)`, use `Mid(path, Len(staticString) + 1)` instead.

Comment: That still does not do what I need because then it doesn't guarantee that the static strings equate, but I figured out my problem overall anyway. Thanks though!

Comment: Please submit your solution as the answer so that this question can help other people.  Thanks.